Call backend service in another container using frontend JS
I have two services in my compose file.
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000" # expose local port
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" # expose local port
    environment:
      - SERV_URL=http://localhost:4000/my-test

The environment variable SERV_URL is used by the frontend service to query the backend service. With the current setup, the frontend JS code that runs in my host browser fails to find the resource at the "localhost:4000/my-test" endpoint. I tried setting up a reverse proxy using nginx as per this QnA. However, that didn't help.
Here are a few sanity checks I have done so far.

Directly query "http://localhost:4000/my-test" from the host web browser. It successfully works.
Directly query the reverse proxy with a re-direct to the internal docker container. It also works.

However, the frontend JS query fails with an HTTP 404 error code. I am lost and would appreciate any guidance.

Also see "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend.  The important trick with the reverse proxy is that you wouldn't include the URL scheme or host name in the URL at all, so it uses the current host and port.  Does just SERV_URL=/my-test work, if you add in the proxy?

Thanks, that's what eventually worked. One thing that helped was to run the web framework (in this case Gin) in release mode. That seemed to have helped.

The issue in my case was that the web framework (Gin) was run in debug mode in the container. This was causing the resource to be not found from the host.
